# Событие JTable (Java)

Tags: java

Ребят, возникла такая задачка: имеется таблица, по нажатию на ее ячейку должно создаться событие. Вот как это сделать я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Спасибо=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `MouseListener`, а в нем уже можно узнать номера столбца и строки (`getSelectedRow` и `getSelectedColumn`).